# JSON Date and DateTime serialisation in c# & newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, date, datetime, json.net

We are sending JSON to an API defined by swagger that some properties are DateTime in the format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z (the milliseconds must be 3 digits or it fails validation at the endpoint) and some are Date (no time) properties.

I have seen many messages saying use the formatters like this:

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z"; //try .fffZ too
var jsonObject= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OurSwaggerObject>(json , setting);
```

but this does not convert the DateTimes into the correct format, and how does C# deal with a Date only type? It always seems to serialise as DateTime.MinValue()

Here is an example:

Someone sends me json as string but the the dates and datetimes in the incorrect format to be sent to the endpoint. I was hoping that the swagger class and json deserialisation would format them but it is not.

This is the swagger generated class

```
 public class OurSwaggerObject
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("dateTimeField", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpression(@"^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}Z$")]
        public DateTime dateTimeField { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("dateField", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpression(@"^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$")]
        public DateTime dateField { get; set; }
    }
```

So I try and coerce the json to be correct but I'm doing it wrong or something is missing

```
string json = @"{ 'dateTimeField': '1995-04-07T00:00:00',
                          'dateField': '1995-04-07T00:00:00'
                           }";

        /* The json we need to satisfy the swagger endpoint is:

          { 'dateTimeField': '1995-04-07T00:00:00.000Z',
            'dateField': '1995-04-07'
                           }              
          */

        OurSwaggerObject deserialisedIntoObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OurSwaggerObject>(json);

        string serialisedToString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialisedIntoObject);
        //serialisedToString= "{\"dateTimeField\":\"1995-04-07T00:00:00\",\"dateField\":\"1995-04-07T00:00:00\"}"

        var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsonSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ"; //this won't help much for the 'date' only field!
        deserialisedIntoObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OurSwaggerObject>(json,jsonSettings);
        serialisedToString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialisedIntoObject, jsonSettings);
        //serialisedToString="{\"dateTimeField\":\"1995-04-07T00:00:00\",\"dateField\":\"1995-04-07T00:00:00\"}"
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem

Comment: Json.NET uses the de-facto standard since version 4.5 (current one is 10.x). It *does* serialize the date correctly. Format strings were only used for *older* versions. Post code that actually shows the problem

Comment: On other hand, if the other endpoint requires an arbitrary number of milliseconds, the problem is theirs. ISO8601 **doesn't** require milliseconds

Comment: As for date only - Json doesn't have dates or times. That's why mentioned the *defacto* standard. At some point people simply decided to start using ISO8601. A date *can* be represented by a DateTime value. You *can* serialize it to Json either as a full ISO8601 string with zero hour,minute, or as a date-only string. All are valid.

Comment: Swagger OpenAPi does define date and datetime https://swagger.io/specification/ I will post up some code example

Comment: In the top part of your question you refer to an `OurSwaggerObject` class, but later in your question you have a class called `Rootobject`.  Are these the same thing?  If not, what is `OurSwaggerObject`?  Secondly, in `Rootobject` the `dateTimeField` and `dateField` properties are defined as `string`.  If you want the Json.Net date format to be respected, these fields need to be defined as `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`.  Lastly, the JSON dates you are passing in have only a single digit for the month and day, but your date formats specify two digits for each.

Comment: @brian you're right. I tried to quickly make a demo after I wrote the question, but maybe it was too quick, there are the errors you've pointed out. I will edit the code.

Comment: @DomBat the OpenAPI links to RFC3999 which says what I explained in comments about ISO8601. Milliseconds are optional. You can have `Z` or an offset. Json.NET follows the standard. If the other endpoint *requires* milliseconds, it has a bug

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, there is no standard date representation in JSON. The ISO8601 is the *de-facto* standard, ie most people started using this some years ago. ISO8601 does *not* require milliseconds. If the other endpoint requires them, it's violating the defacto standard.

Json.NET has been using IOS8601 since version 4.5. The current one is 10.0.3. The following code :

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now)
```

returns

```
"2017-09-08T19:01:55.714942+03:00"
```

On my machine. Notice the timezone offset. That's also part of the standard. `Z` means UTC.

You *can* specify your own time format, provided it's the correct one. In this case, it should be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ`. Notice the `fff` for milliseconds **and** `HH` for 24-hour.

The following code

```
var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings{DateFormatString ="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"};
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now,settings);
```

returns

```
"2017-09-08T19:04:14.480Z"
```

The format string does *not* force a timezone translation. You can tell Json.NET to treat the time as Local or Utc through the DateTimeZoneHandling setting :

```
var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings{
                              DateFormatString ="yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffZ",
                              DateTimeZoneHandling=DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc};
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now,settings);
```

Returns :

```
"2017-09-08T16:08:19.290Z"
```

**UPDATE**

As Matt Johnson explains, `Z` is just a literal, while `K` generates either `Z` or an offset, depending on the `DateTimeZoneHandling` setting.

The format string `yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffK` with DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc :

```
var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings{
                              DateFormatString ="yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffK",
                              DateTimeZoneHandling=DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc};
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now,settings);
```

Will return :

```
2017-09-11T9:10:08.293Z
```

Changing to `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` will return

```
2017-09-11T12:15:12.862+03:00
```

Which, by the way is the *default* behaviour of Json.NET, apart from the forced millisecond precision.

Finally, .NET doesn't have a `Date`-only type *yet*. DateTime is used for both dates and date+time values. You can get the date part of a DateTime with the [DateTime.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You can retrieve the current date with [DateTime.Today](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx).

Time of day is represented by the Timespan type. You can extract the time of day from a DateTime value with [DateTime.TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx). `Timespan` isn't *strictly* a time-of-day type as it can represent more than 24 hours.

**What was that *yet*?**

Support for explicit Date, TimeOfDay is comming through the [CoreFX Lab project](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab). This contains "experimental" features that are *extremely* likely to appear in the .NET Runtime like UTF8 support, Date, String, Channles. Some of these already appear as separate NuGet packages.

One can use the [System.Time](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src/System.Time/System) classes already, either by copying the code or adding them through the experimental NuGet source

Comment: `Z` in a format string is a *literal*.  You should use `K`, which properly reflects the `DateTimeKind` associated with the `DateTime` in question.

Comment: True - I never had to *hand-code* the ISO8601 format

Comment: Interestingly enough when I use this `var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings{DateFormatString ="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"};
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now,settings);` it produces this
`"effective": {
      "start": "\"2021-04-09T09:52:47.170Z\"",
      "end": "\"2023-04-08T09:52:47.170Z\""
    },`
NOTE the additional speech marks and \

Answer (score 3):

Get current universaltime to json date time format and vice versa:

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
var jsonDateTime = GetJSONFromUserDateTime(currentDateTime);
DateTime getDateTime = GetUserDateTimeFromJSON(jsonDateTime);
```

Here are both methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert UserDateTime({9/7/2018 8:37:20 AM}) to JSON datetime(1536309440373) format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="givenDateTime"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetJSONFromUserDateTime(DateTime givenDateTime)
{
    string jsonDateTime = string.Empty;
    if (givenDateTime != null)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };
        jsonDateTime = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(givenDateTime, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
        jsonDateTime = jsonDateTime.Replace("\"\\/Date(", "").Replace(")\\/\"", "");
    }
    return jsonDateTime;
}

/// <summary>
/// Convert JSON datetime(1536309440373) to user datetime({9/7/2018 8:37:20 AM})
/// </summary>
/// <param name="jsonDateTime"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static dynamic GetUserDateTimeFromJSON(string jsonDateTime)
{
    dynamic userDateTime = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonDateTime))
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };
        userDateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("\"\\/Date(" + jsonDateTime + ")\\/\"", microsoftDateFormatSettings);
    }
    return userDateTime;
}
```

Comment: About Deserialize from JSON I can add that somethimes you get a shorter number like from the OpenweatherMap API and the solution in this case is to multiplicate the number to 1000 and use your function GetUserDateTimeFromJSON.

Answer (score 1):

If, like Willie Esteche you wish to convert a number that is too low, you have probably got a Unix Date Time value.  His solution does indeed work, but as of .Net Framework 4.6 there is an easier way to do things.

Given a value of 1500013000, first you convert this to a DateTimeOffset with the FromUnixTimeSeconds() method, then simply grab the DateTime component.

```
DateTime dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1500013000).UtcDateTime;
```

Conversion back (assuming UTC) is performed like so:

```
long Udt = new DateTimeOffset(dt,TimeSpan.Zero).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
```

Comment: It's simple and humble. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i using this config in vb.net, it's so easy translate to c #

```
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
BE = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of EN_BE)(str, settings)
```

I get this format date from laravel API

```
2020-08-02T01:41:05.000000Z
```

and i convert to correct value same to database

```
2020-08-01 20:41:05
```