# JSON JObject.Parse modifies json string

Tags: c#, json, parsing, uwp

I have got incomming Json in format:

```
{
    "Type": "value",
    "Name": "MeteoStation",
    "UniqueAdress": "2C:3A:E8:0F:10:76",
    "valuesList": [{
        "Value": 23.00,
        "Unit": "C",
        "Type": "temperature",
        "SourceUniqAdress": "2C:3A:E8:0F:10:76",
        "TimeCaptured": "2018-03-26T09:36:13.200Z"
    }]
}
```

In my program, I want to create object IValuePacket that is one value in list of values.

```
JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(incomingJson);
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
};
var incommingMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageEncapsulation>(incomingJson);
string Type = incommingMessage.Type;
string name = incommingMessage.Name;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    name = "no name";

if (Type.ToLower().Equals("value")) {
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IValuePacket>>(jobject["valuesList"].ToString());
}
```

Everything works fine untill I recieved exact this json as mention above.
JObject.Parse modifies value TimeCaptured and jobject looks like:

```
{
"Type": "value",
"Name": "Meteostation",
"UniqueAdress": "2C:3A:E8:0F:10:76",
"valuesList": [{
    "Value": 23.00,
    "Unit": "C",
    "Type": "temperature",
    "SourceUniqAdress": "2C:3A:E8:0F:10:76",
    "TimeCaptured": "2018-03-26T09:36:13.2Z"
}]}
```

Thats not so much difference, but `DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` cannot parse new value. Actually, I am sending 201 ms instead of 200 ms. It works, but I want to have good time for future reasons.

Is there any way how to avoid changing in `Json` during parsing?

Comment: there is an overload for DateTime.ParseExact, which allows you to pass multiple formats https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So wait, are you actually losing precision, or just zeroes?

Comment: @Nyerguds just zeroes. Precision is the same

Comment: Then, doesn't that mean that it is _already parsed_ by something at that point? Otherwise it can't know those zeroes are superfluous.

Comment: I dont understand what are you asking. There is only one parsing. From correct string into incorrect jsonobject. Then, I am trying to parse DateTime from incorect jsonobject that throws incorrect format excepton.

Comment: This link may help [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120116/json-date-and-datetime-serialisation-in-c-sharp-newtonsoft)

Comment: if you can change format type to "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.FFFZ" it will handle both cases with or without trailing zeros in milliseconds (upper case F matters) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not really modify your string, it just parses your date string into `DateTime` object when you call `JObject.Parse`. If you do this:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var values = (JArray) obj["valuesList"];
var time = (JValue) values[0]["TimeCaptured"];
Console.WriteLine(time.Value.GetType());
```

You notice that `time.Value` is of type `DateTime`. Then you do this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IValuePacket>>(jobject["valuesList"].ToString());
```

By doing that you convert `valueList` back to json, but now `TimeCaptured` is `DateTime` and not a string, so that `DateTime` object is converted to json string using whatever date time format is used by JSON.NET by default.

You can avoid parsing strings that look like dates to .NET `DateTime` objects by parsing json to `JObject` like this:

```
JObject obj;
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json))) {
    // DateParseHandling.None is what you need
    reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
    obj = JObject.Load(reader);
}
```

Then type of `TimeCaptured` will be string, as you expect.

Side note: there is no need to convert `JToken` back to string and then call `JsonConvert.Deserialize` on that string. Instead, do this:

```
var values = obj["valuesList"].ToObject<List<IValuePacket>>();
```